# Como mostrar cuantos registros tiene cada items en una tabla SQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una tabla que quisiera añadirle un conteo para saber cuantas personas tiene cada estructura pero lo he realizdo de varias formas y me da error en todas, el codigo de mi tabla es la siguiente:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                      <thead class="thead-dark">
                              <th class="text-light">Nombre</th>
                              <th class="text-light">Población</th>
                              <th class="text-light"><i class="mdi mdi-image-filter-vintage"></i></th>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
                          <?php
                        //incluimos el fichero de conexion
                        include_once('../../../config/dbconect.php');

                        $database = new Connection();
                        $db = $database->open();
                        try{
                          $id = $row['id_estructuras_nivel'];
                          $sql = "SELECT * FROM data_estructuras where id_estructuras_nivel = $id";
                          foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
                            ?>
                  <tr>
                              <td class="table-info"><?php echo $row['nombre_estructuras']; ?></td>
                              <td class="table-success">0</td>
                              <td class="table-primary"><i class="mdi mdi-menu float-right"></i></td>
                              <td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php 
                          }
                        }
                        catch(PDOException $e){
                          echo "Hubo un problema en la conexi璐竛: " . $e->getMessage();
                        }

                        //Cerrar la Conexion
                        $database->close();

                      ?>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Como seria el conteo, en la tabla data_estructuras el id es id_estructuras, y en la tabla data_personas, se encuentra el id_estructuras, ese seria el posible INNER JOIN para saber cuantas personas hay en cada estructura, pero, lo intente hacer y me trae solo el primero en todas, cabe destacar que esa tabla se muestra  en un modal cuando selecciono el id_estructuras_nivel. que formas puedo tener para poder tener esa consulta, ayuda, la idea es que en la columna poblacion me diga cuantas personas tienen el mismo id_estructuras

Answer (score 0):

No colocas la estructura de las tablas involucradas, entonces suponiendo que tienes algo así:

`data_estructuras`

```
id_estructuras | nombre_estructuras 
---------------+-------------------
 1             | Estructura_A
 2             | Estructura_B
 3             | Estructura_C
```

`data_personas`

```
id_personas | id_estructuras |nombre_personas
------------+----------------+--------------
 1          | 2              | Juan
 2          | 2              | Pedro
 3          | 1              | Maria
 4          | 2              | Jose
 5          | 1              | Sara
 6          | 3              | Marcos
```

Para contar todos los usuarios por estructura:

```sql
SELECT E.nombre_estructuras, count(*) as Cant 
FROM data_personas P 
INNER JOIN data_estructuras E ON E.id_estructuras=P.id_estructuras
-- WHERE P.id_estructuras=[El_id] -- Para contar solo una estructura
GROUP BY P.id_estructuras
```

Da como resultado:

```
nombre_estructuras | Cantidad
-------------------+---------
Estructura_A       | 2
Estructura_B       | 3
Estructura_C       | 1
```

Puedes traer la columna `id_estructuras` en vez de `nombre_estructuras`, o ambas.

Si quieres contar solo los usuarios de una estructura en particular, descomenta la línea en la consulta.